# Jurisdictions having no common point over a certain issue

Tags: international, comparative-law

Let's say there's an adult man from a western country having no extraterritorial jurisdiction and does an act in an African country that would be abhorrent and obviously illegal accordint to the laws of his country but it's legal in the country he's doing the act in. 
According to my logic he wouldn't meet chargen in none of the two countries because, as mentioned;

-the country he's from doesn't have extraterritorial jurisdiction

-the country he does the act in  doesn't mandate penalty or prosecution for the former act

so, as far as my layman international law knowledge is concerned (yup, it's pretty little), there's no common intersection between the two countries' laws for which the man can be charged and prosecuted, hence he could even show a video of him doing the thing in front of a police station, if the video shows clearly that the thing is done in that country.

Am I wrong here? Obviously, the question is hypothetical in nature and don't tell me "it depends upon the 2 countries", because I stated the conditions that leave no ambiguity or genericness in the situation above.

Comment: On the "show the video in front of the police station," having or displaying the video would have to not be illegal in country A also. For example, child molestation is illegal, but so is having videos depicting such acts, and more so displaying videos of such acts.

Comment: Ok, in that case the other crime applies, but what if he simply tells it to a cop during a conversation only? Does the crime apply in that case too?

Comment: As stated in the existing answers, iff the conditions on your scenario are so specific and tight, then he gets away with it. Usually things that are so abhorrent are not exempt from what you are calling extraterritorial jurisdiction, but there are more than 200 countries in the world so it is possible.

Comment: I didn't say that those things are exempt from extraterritorial jurisdiction, I mentioned a case in which the perpetrator's country doesn't have it. That's different.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not arguing with you. Just stating that finding a trifecta of country A- no EJ at all, country B- legal, AND the act is abhorrent might not in fact exist. Maybe it does. Add in that the victim better not be a citizen of a country that makes doing the thing to their citizen a crime.

Comment: Obviously that's included if I said that the act is legal in B-country.

Comment: I might think that it exists. Take a third world country and a western one that doesn't prosecute its citizens or his PR abroad for things that might be a crime in its territory, there aren't only a few cases, but I should look it up.

Comment: Look into it. Your condition was that it be something abhorrent also, not just ilegal..

Comment: But in that case abhorrent or illegal, legally speaking (not morally, that is different and a lot!!!!) is irrelevant, because there'd be no conditions for which any of the two countries can take action against a potential man, unless the western country decides to break its own rules and condemn him anyway, if it gets to know it. That's the only way. On a moral basis, that would make sense, but not on a legal way, because eventually the western country would have to go against one of its own laws, logically speaking. Maybe the case can be appealed to an International court, that's another way

Comment: I mean if the country prosecutes a certain individual regardless of its EJ-related laws it would be a fair thing for me, but logically speaking it'd be illegal in the sense that it'd be contradictory, but a state wouldn't be punished by its own self for such a thing. Maybe my assumption are purely theoretical, in a pragmatic scenario morality and common sense would prevail with a fair judge (or a person who follow the case and has a big hand over it) who doesn't care about technicalities and paves all the way with his feelings.

Comment: I mean, most probably if the people managing the case apply some common sense is a thing, but if they're just technical and picky-formal people it'd be a total different story.

Answer (score 2):

Break down the question into its two main parts:

Will country A prosecute the person for an act in country B if country A has no jurisdiction? No.

Will country B prosecute the person for an act in country B if it's not a criminal offence in country B? No.

Therefore it's obvious that the person will not be prosecuted by country A or B.

Comment: Ok, I thought that for abhorrent, vile and utmost disgusting acts there would be exemptions and rule breakings. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: BTW I didn't ask whether B country punishes people for things that are not a crime in its territory, I asked whether the man would be totally left alone, even if A was to know it or the person was to tell it to a cop.

Comment: @us-er  We can only speculate about the extralegal (i.e. outside the legal system) things that a state or its inhabitants might do to such a person.

Comment: Only if they know about it, otherwise either an supranational court involves itself in the case or the western country breaks its own laws and asks the president or highest charge to proceed either way.

Comment: If the perpetrator is known (through spying and tracking techniques such as chats and calls) to go to a 3 world country and commit things then those are the available options, otherwise....nisba, nothing will occur to him and can potentially reiterate that as many times as he wishes, the only boundaries left for him would be money and time. I hope that's not the case.

Comment: @user If it’s so abhorrent, then either the second country would have a law against it or the first country would exercise extraterritorial jurisdiction over it. If neither of those is true, it suggests it really isn’t that abhorrent.

Comment: As I said, there may be western countries which do not have ETJ for their own citizens  and third world countries that allow acts that would be deemed abhorrent in mainland world, and that would be enough to leave room to unpunished abhorrent acts, otherwise it means that either the country of the perpetrator DOES enact EJT or that the 3rd world country jurisdiction punishes the act, whilst I assumed that both countries don't do these respective things.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, there are such “crimes”

For example, possession of cannabis is illegal in, say [Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_Indonesia), but legal in, say [Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_laws_of_Canada_by_province_or_territory). An Indonesian citizen in Canada can possess cannabis without legal consequence.

Comment: Exactly, but I do not know whether this applies for the most abhorrent acts.

Comment: “The most abhorrent acts” is a little vague. For example, murder is illegal in both Canada and Indonesia but blasphemy is only illegal in Indonesia. Some people consider the latter more “abhorrent” than the former; just not most Canadians.

Comment: Well, then it means that the overall question depends on how the two jurisdictions deal with the situations, and since I assumed that one of them has hypothetically no issue, then it's up to the other one, and it may be that it'd go against its own laws if required.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it quite unlikely that a country consideres a certain crime “abhorrent and obviously illegal” but at the same time doesn't assume extraterritorial jurisdiction. In the unlikely event that this happens, neither country A nor country B would prosecute the act in question. However, “abhorrent and obviously illegal” crimes would still quite likely be subject to extra-territorial jurisdiction in otherwise unrelated countries C, D and E so an offender would have to plan very carefully where he travels.

As an example, I suggest that you take a look at § 4 et seq. StGB which governs the application of German penal law to crimes committed abroad.

§4 - Application to offences committed on German ships and aircraft
§5 - Offenses committed abroad with specific domestic connection
§6 - Offences committed abroad against internationally protected legal interests
§7 - Other offences committed abroad

For instance, if you tamper with an ATM in Somalia and Somali authorities don't care, you can be arrested and put on trial in Germany, no matter what your nationality is. (Sect. 6 para. 1 sentence 1 item 7 StGB)

https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html

Comment: Then in this case ETJ is applied, so it does not match the scenario. Anyway, it seems weird that, as per this answer, Germany could prosecute a Somali man for a thing committed in Somalia whilst Somali authoriries do not care. That's weird

Comment: Well, if no ETJ is being applied by country A, then neither country A nor country B would prosecute the act. However, if the act is “abhorrent and obviously illegal”, I would consider it quite likely that either country A or an otherwise unrelated country C would assume to have ETJ.

Comment: Firstly, I thank you for being participant in the conversation, secondly, how can you say that a third, unrelated country would indulge itself into something that is not of its competence?

Comment: Could you mean that USA would involve in such situations, even if it has no take in it?

Comment: I mean, this would be possible if the perpetrator goes in that country C, but assuming that the perpetrator's never been in C, how can they simply go and arrest him?

Comment: The US ... Well, in practise it will surely depend on whether US authorities care about the case. Legally, we would have to look into US law to determine when ETJ is assumed by the US; I'm not familiar with US penal law. What I know for sure though is that there are certain international treaties that require certain acts to be prosecuted, no matter where committed. For instance, forgery of postage stamps should get you into jail in any country that is party to the Treaty of Bern (i. e. pretty much everywhere), no matter where you've been forging the stamps or which postal operator was hurt.

Comment: So are you entailing that there are cases in which international law takes precedence over the analytical outcome due to the combination of the perpetrator's country and the perpetration's country?

Comment: The case you've just mentioned doesn't leave room for no punishment whatsoever, as there are common ground for multiple jurisdictions involved, and if a country falls short, there may be another, and in this case ETJ is still applied. The case mentioned in the OP entails no common ground for prosecution and leaves room for no punishment, at least analytically. But if you say that there may be a country "A" that may punish a person that has never been in  its own territory, nor do they have any link with it and nor have they committed a crime against one of its own citizens, how can ....

Comment: ...there be ground for any prosecution??

Comment: Well, if the perpetrator doesn't travel to country C, it can get difficult for country C to arrest the perpetrator. Possible options would include:

• Convince another country D to extradite the perpetrator (may or may not work, it depends)
• Arrest the perpetrator in international waters
• Invade the foreign country and just take the perpetrator out of country (this can be straight-forward if the country is already occupied or if it lacks a functioning administration)
• Don't arrest the perpetrator but instead seize assets belonging to the perpetrator that are within reach of country C

Comment: But then this would entail that country C has worldwide ETJ over anybody in the world to a certain extent and in case there's no liability for the act that might be internationally abhorrent and unacceptable, or it may mean that country C may go againts its own laws and international law as well (according to the latter, sovereignity principles subsists, henceforth local law takes precedence), which leads me to think that laws may be broken when it's more befitting

Comment: Well, take a look at § 6 StGB:<br />

“§ 6 - Offences committed abroad against internationally protected legal interests<br />

Regardless of which law is applicable at the place where they are committed, German criminal law further applies to the following offences committed abroad: [...]”<br />

If you have committed one of the crimes listed in §6 StGB you can only avoid prosecution in Germany by either staying out of reach of German law enforcement or by being put on trial in another jurisdiction. In the latter case, you won't be punished twice (non bis in idem).

Comment: Ok, I think we're getting to the basic point of this. So you think that each country should only have penal jurisdiction for actions connected to it? While I sort of agree with that I also feel that as a universal rule, certain “abhorrent and outright illegal” crimes (such as murder or misuse of ionizing radiation) should be subject to prosecution, no matter where committed, and that's the idea behind §6 StGB in Germany, similar legislation in other countries and international treaties.

Comment: Morally I agree with you, don't get me wrong, but formally speaking I was wondering whether in a scenario in which there's no common intersection between two jurisdictions there would be a sorting-out or not. And by this I mean that only the countries connected to the perpetrator and the jurisdiction of the crime place being involvedn otherwise this would mean that an other country could get involved and result not minding its own business. I absolutely do NOT endorse crime; I want this to be clear.

Comment: Because I hardly imagine US police entering, for example, UK, and arresting a citizen of Sierra Leone that committed a thing in his own country which is abhorrent but legal in the latter jurisdiction. Legally there's no ground.

Comment: Regarding Germany, it means that it doesn't mind its own business. I am of the idea that every country can enforce for its own jurisdiction and the internal acts committed and about its own citizens actions only. This is my idea, otherwise every country could break its own laws and render the concept of law that they impose literally meaningless, unless there are specific exemption (such as applying and mentioning ETJ and what).

Answer (score -1):

There are countries which have laws that prohibit citizens from doing some things, no matter where.

There are countries that ban certain actions for everyone, no matter where the action took place. So if you are ever in this country, you might be prosecuted. (e.g. you go from A to B, do something legal in B, go back to A but you might be prosecuted in C)

Some countries assert jurisdiction over crimes against their citizens, so if you go from country A to B, and commit a crime against a citizen of country C, which is not a crime in B, country C can prosecute you, even if you are back in A.

There are multinational courts, which could prosecute you.

Without going into more specifics about the action or the countries the only possible answer is:

**Yes, you are wrong here!**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104771/discussion-on-answer-by-josef-says-reinstate-monica-jurisdictions-having-no-comm).